# CKEditor yellow marker not working in inline method

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I'm using `CK editor 4.11.0` for my project. I have a concern with `marker` where it is highlighting yellow color if the `CK editor` initialized with the `replace` method, not in `inline` method. I tried the following method suggested [here](https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/11090) but no luck. can anyone have tricks to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

I solve the issue by clicking 'Source' of ckeditor toolbar button and adding style in 'marker' class.

Normal code:

```
<p><span class="marker">Lorem ipsum dolor...</span</p>
```

After styling:

```
<p><span class="marker" style="background-color:yellow">Lorem ipsum dolor...</span</p>
```

And it works amazingly!!!